# Show that there exist $a,b\in[0,4],(f(4))^2-(f(0))^2=8f'(a)f(b)$

Tags: calculus

Let $f:[0,4]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function.

(i) Show that there exist $a,b\in[0,4]$,
$(f(4))^2-(f(0))^2=8f'(a)f(b)$.

(ii) Show that there exist $\alpha,\beta$ with $0<\alpha<\beta<2$ such that $\int_{0}^{4}f(t)dt=2(\alpha f(\alpha^2))+\beta f(\beta^2))$.

---

I tried to apply mean value theorem,but could not succeed.
$(f(4))^2-(f(0))^2=8f'(a)f(b)\implies\frac{f(4)-f(0)}{4-0}\cdot (f(4)+f(0))=2f'(a)f(b)$

Answer (score 5):

(i) $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx}(f(x))^2=2f(x)f'(x)$

By MVT, $\exists c\in(0,4)$ such that

$$\frac{(f(4))^2-(f(0))^2}{4-0}=2f(c)f'(c)$$

$$(f(4))^2-(f(0))^2=8f(c)f'(c)$$

(ii) Let $u=\sqrt{t}$.

$$\int_0^4f(t)dt=2\int_0^2 uf(u^2)du$$

By MVT for integrals, $\exists \xi\in[0,2]$ such that

$$\int_0^2 uf(u^2)du=(2-0)\xi f(\xi^2)$$

Answer (score 2):

As regards (i), you are on the right track.

As you already remarked, by  Mean Value Theorem, there is $a\in (0,4)$ such that
$$\frac{f(4)-f(0)}{4-0}=f'(a).$$
Moreover, by Intermediate Value Theorem there is $b\in [0,4]$ such that
$$[\min(f(0),f(4)),\max(f(0),f(4))]\ni\frac{f(4)+f(0)}{2}=f(b).$$
Hence
$$f^2(4)-f^2(0)=(f(4)-f(0))(f(4)+f(0))=4f'(a)\cdot 2f(b)=8f'(a)f(b).$$

For (ii), consider the differentiable function
$$F(x):=\int_0^x f(t)dt=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{x}} f(s^2) 2s ds$$
in the interval $[0,4]$.